# Use of parallel / serial port redirection to transfer data from Terminal desktop to local computer

Tags: terminal, serial-port, rdp, parallel-port

Amongst features of terminal desktop services running RDP port, there is port redirection of parallel/serial from remote to local PC.

Can this redirection be somehow used to transfer large data to avoid using Clipboard (due to the known stack bug which may force user to close terminal desktop and re-logon)?

To transmit and receive data I'd use VBA for Excel on both terminal desktop as well as in local PC. Both would be running infinetely or at the same time.

Please advise if it's possible.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I'm sure there are better ways of moving data between two computers. Why don't you use drive mapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least one company makes [a library](http://www.adontec.com/index.htm?GO=/super_e.htm) for doing Kermit (i.e. serial file transfer), which includes VBA support and samples for Access, Excel and Word.

It's not cheap though, and there are *a lot* of better ways of sending data around than serial file transfer protocols over virtual serial ports so I'd strongly consider better alternatives (file sharing, TCP sockets etc.).